# Variable for Use [Database]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to run this query to change the database while running a script.

```
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200)

SELECT @Command = 'USE [Database1]' 

--PRINT @Command 
EXECUTE sp_sqlexec @Command
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: But it works. Do You have any error?

Comment: **sp_sqlexec** is still supported? I thought we have missed that from early SQL version onwards. Try sp_executesql or EXEC (@Command) instead

Comment: Might be worth mentioning, because of the way `USE` works, you can't execute this in a batch and then execute code in the same batch expecting it to have issued a `USE` in the current scope. Any code that needs to be run under the scope of the `USE` needs to also be executed in the same batch (e.g. in the dynamic SQL string)

Answer (score 2):

Try just to use it before your script

```
USE [Database1]
GO
```

You do not have to use variable for that, but if you want dynamic then try

```
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200), @DatabaseName nvarchar(200)
SET @Command = 'USE @DatabaseName
       GO;' 
SET @DatabaseName = 'Database1'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Command, '@DatabaseName', @DatabaseName
```

or

```
EXEC ('Use Database1')
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to achieve this in dynamic query instead.

Comment: My up vote. Please mention about sp_executesql too because sp_sqlexec is quite old (SQL Server 6.5 - if I am correct)

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. Now I have the opportunity to also make upvote. Cool. Thanks for advice